# Section script ends before expected JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have some JavaScript which has two parts as I marked in the code, when I add the second part my section script automatically detect somewhere else to close the section, if I don't add that part its fine im sorry if its messy

```
@section Scripts{
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    var myResult;



    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        var mydata;

        if (e.which == 13) {

            var drp = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("turbineDeviceDetail","AdminTool")",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "turbine": drp, }),

                success: function (result) {
                    myResult = result;
                    var flg = "s";
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("producersDevice","AdminTool")",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "flg": flg, }),
                        success: function (data) {
                            mydata = data;
                        }
                    })
                    var flg_dvType = "s";
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("deviceTypeList","AdminTool")",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "flg": flg_dvType, }),
                        success: function (data) {
                            mydata_deviceType = data;
                        }
                    });




                    //

                    ////

                    function ProductNameDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                        $('<input  name="Producer" data-type="string"\">')
                          .appendTo(container)
                          .kendoDropDownList({
                              valuePrimitive: true,
                              dataSource: mydata,
                              dataTextField: "Text",
                              dataValueField: "Text",
                          });
                    }

                    function deviceTypesList(container, options) {
                        $('<input  name="DeviceType" data-type="string" \">')
                          .appendTo(container)
                          .kendoDropDownList({
                              dataSource: mydata_deviceType,
                              dataTextField: "Text",
                              dataValueField: "Text",

                              //dataValueField: "ProductName",


                          });

                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });


    //This Part Is For The AUTOCOMPLETE textbox
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("List_Turbine","AdminTool")",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //data: JSON.stringify({ "name": value ,}),
                data: {},

                success: function (result) {

                    $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
                        dataSource: result,
                        dataTextField: "Text",


                        // filter: "contains"

                    });


                }
            })

        });







    $(document).ready(function () {

        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({


            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    options.success(myResult); // where data is the local data array
                },
                update: function (options) {
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/Update",
                        data: options.data.models[0],
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            options.success(data);
                            // alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            options.error(data);
                            //  alert("error");
                        },
                    });
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },


            //},
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            schema: {
                //data: employee,
                model: {
                    id: "ProductID",
                    fields: {
                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        firstName: { validation: { required: true } },
                        lastName: { validation: { required: true } },
                        //UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                        //Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                        //UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        $("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
            //   debugger;

            dataSource: result,
            scrollable: false,
            columns: [
                                  { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                                  { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor, },
                                  { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '120px' },
                                  { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px', editor: deviceTypesList },
                                  { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '100px' },
                                  { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                                  { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                                  { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
                                  { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }],
            editable: "popup",
            edit:
                function () {
                    document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].disabled = true;

                },
            editable: "popup"
        });


        });

        </script>
```

Comment: What is that `@section` stuff? That's not Javascript.

Comment: means the section is I can put js,I as I heard,even if I remove that section stuff and put my java script sources up there,i still get the syntax error

Comment: Which statement is the syntax error on?

Comment: Put your error in your question thanx...

Comment: Can you remove the code that is not related to the error and post the console output of your browser? Perhaps log some values with console.log like is suggested before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sort out the error first:**

Javascript won't continue down an execution thread once it has encountered an error. It is completely possible that your code is there, *but it is just not reached*.

**Troubleshoot:**

If I were you, I'd verify using the developer console (F12) what my errors are, and check the actual DOM if my script is there.

*From here you will have a much better base to debug from.*

Good Luck

PS: Perhaps if you found your error, you can edit your post to include it.

## EDIT

It seems that your problem is with a `}` closing your `@section` block prematurely. *This is the only explanation if your code is not in the DOM.*

**Comb through your code and find where your syntax error is located.**

Comment: the problem is "syntax error" which is the worst error with no clue

Comment: @mortezasol The error message should include the line number. Which line in the code is it?

Comment: Yep, check the line number as @Barmar said, and if I can add some further advice use console.log(). That is another way to see where your JS is breaking.

Comment: I edited it,the error is the last )}  which says sytax error,and  needs '}',but even if I do that,when I run the page I only see '}'  in the page